# lgetxattr can't get security.capability

Tags: linux, kernel, c, xattr

**Background** : in ima-evm-utils I found lgetxattr() can't return expected value.I wrote a simple c program to verify it.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        char xattr_value[1024];
        int size;
        size=lgetxattr("/bin/tcpm", "security.capability", xattr_value, sizeof(xattr_value));
        printf("caps: %s\n", &xattr_value);
        printf("%d\n",size);
        size=lgetxattr("/bin/tcpm", "security.selinux", xattr_value, sizeof(xattr_value));
        printf("selinux: %s\n", &xattr_value);
        printf("%d\n",size);
        return 0;
}

[root@localhost ~]# ./a.out 
caps:  
20
selinux: system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
27

[root@localhost ~]# getcap /bin/tcpm
/bin/tcpm cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin=ep

[root@localhost ~]# getfattr -m - -d /bin/tcpm
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: bin/tcpm
security.capability=0sAQAAAgAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
security.selinux="system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0"
```

**size is not -1 means lgetxattr() suceess,but xattr_value is not expected value**
**try to gdb ima-evm-utils: #err = return of lgetxattr()**

```
(gdb) p err
$6 = 20
(gdb) p xattr_value
$7 = "\000\000\000\002\000 ", '\000' <repeats 14 times>, "P\261\037&@&^\a\022\274fOT\031", '\000' <repeats 294 times>...
(gdb) p err
$8 = 27
(gdb) p  xattr_value 
$9 = "system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0", '\000' <repeats 302 times>...
```

source code of this probelm:

```
for (xattrname = evm_config_xattrnames; *xattrname != NULL; xattrname++) {
        err = lgetxattr(file, *xattrname, xattr_value, sizeof(xattr_value));
        if (err < 0) {
            log_info("no xattr: %s\n", *xattrname);
            continue;
        }
        if (!find_xattr(list, list_size, *xattrname)) {
            log_info("skipping xattr: %s\n", *xattrname);
            continue;
        }
        log_info("name: %s, size: %d\n", *xattrname, err);
        log_debug_dump(xattr_value, err);
        err = !HMAC_Update(pctx, xattr_value, err);
        if (err) {
            log_err("HMAC_Update() failed\n");
            goto out_ctx_cleanup;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getxattr or lgetxattr get the binary capability value in fact.

```
[root@localhost ~]# strace -e getxattr getfattr -d -m - /bin/tcpm
getxattr("/bin/tcpm", "security.capability", NULL, 0) = 20
getxattr("/bin/tcpm", "security.capability", "\0\0\0\2\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 256) = 20
```